# What is the advantage of the web sockets over regular sockets if you are not writing a web app, and your clients won't be a browser?

Tags: java, c++, sockets, networking, websocket

There are some literature on the differences between WebSockets and sockets on Stackoverflow. What I'm trying to understand, is why would I pick web sockets over normal sockets, if I'm writing a normal client/server application, where the server is not necessarily a web server and the clients connecting to the server is a native C++ or a Java client.

There's a huge advantage to WebSockets if you have to deal with browsers, what if I don't have to support browsers, should I still consider using WebSockets?

**Edit:**

More clarity to what I'm asking: Had WebSockets existed much earlier, would it be appropreate to replace https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket with WebSocket in the unix tools that use Unix domain socket for instance, or any other context where sockets are used in an IPC context. Another case would be if you were to write an IRC server, would you it be appropriate to use WebSocket instead of the ordinary TCP socket, is there any reason to stay away from WebSocket in this case?

Comment: **WEB** sockets are for **WEB** applications.... the rest is network applications....

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ I know that, I'm trying to understand should I consider WebSocket for a normal network application, or is it better to stick with regular sockets.

Comment: Well, since you probably want to pick some already designed and implemented protocol, the question should be more about what are the requirements of your application and what existing protocol matches up best with your needs.  Heck, if you're doing file transfer, you may want ftp.  If you're doing request/response, you may just want http with a JSON payload.  There are hundreds of options that span the gamut depending upon your needs.  Also, you probably want to pick something that has a really good developer community around it and an active repository.

Comment: If you use a plain socket, you have transport/parsing related code to write yourself just to pass a simple message from one end to the other.  That is all done for you already with webSocket (or even easier with socket.io built on top of webSocket).  The same is true for many other protocols that are already built.  In most cases, there are lots of reasons to use an existing design and implementation rather than build your own from scratch.

Comment: WebSocket has not much to do with the "Web" except that it uses HTTP/HTTPS for setup. It is basically a breakout protocol, aka "I want to do something other than client->server web requests". In particular, caching and other things you can do with HTTP request metadata goes out of the window. Comparing this to standard TCP sockets: Standard TCP sockets are like a railway line, where you need to bring your own tools and materials to build your train. Websockets already provide a little electric locomotive and an unadorned flatbed railway carriage on which you can build a wooden cabin.

Comment: See also [RFC6455 design philosophy](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#section-1.5): "Other than that, WebSocket adds nothing.  Basically it is intended to be as close to just exposing raw TCP to script as possible given the constraints of the Web.  It's also designed in such a way that its servers can share a port with HTTP servers, by having its handshake be a valid HTTP Upgrade request. ... the intent of WebSockets is to provide a relatively simple protocol that can coexist with HTTP and deployed HTTP infrastructure (such as proxies) and that is as close to TCP as is safe for use..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're comparing WebSockets to TCP, WebSockets have a number of advantages:

- Unicode support
- Datagram-oriented interactions
- HTTP CONNECT-based firewall traversal

However, this comparison is a bit of a false dichotomy.  If you don't use WebSockets, you're not forced to start building directly on TCP.  There are many other protocols out there (too many to count) with many great implementations.

Perhaps HTTP itself is well-suited to your application.  Or maybe XMPP or Google Protocol Buffers or something else.  It all depends on what your application needs to communicate.

Before you can select a protocol (or, rarely, design your own), you need to figure out what kind of communication your application needs to do.  Then you can evaluate different protocols and decide which fit your problem well.

That said, the majority of development these days seems to focus around the web.  Even if there's nothing inherently web-y about the application, many people choose HTTP as their protocol now.  At this point, a ton of work has gone in to standardizing the use of HTTP as the solution for a wide range of problems, as well as building libraries to facilitate this use.  Chances are, whatever you're building, HTTP will be a decent fit (again, I don't know what you're building, so this is just a guess).

Comment: Thanks for the insight, it's exactly what I was looking for.